# Spacemacs layers for working with Zotero in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

Does anyone know if there are any Spacemacs layers written for working with Zotero in org-mode?
I am thinking particularly of layers incorporating the gists: org-pdcite and aj-org-zotxt-configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is my private Spacemacs layer. It may help giving you ideas.

https://github.com/psamim/dotfiles/tree/master/spacemacs/private/psamim-org-zotero

Comment: Thank you, Samim. That looks very useful. I will give it a try.